How to mount a Windows folder in WSL (Debian) with fstab?
I have a folder I want to mount at start-up in WSL (2.3.24.0 running a Debian image) - I can mount it manually with sudo mount -t drvfs c:/projects/source/repos /mnt/repos but when I add it to /etc/fstab I get a start-up message Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
My fstab looks like this:
C:\\projects\\source\\repos /mnt/repos drvfs defaults,bind 0 0

What do I need to do to mount this folder at start-up every time?
